# Photon propagator in terms of creation/annihilation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

As far as I understand it the photon propagator, $P(A\rightarrow B)$, described in Feynman's QED book, gives the amplitude that a photon moves from spacetime point A to spacetime point B.

I was wondering if in quantum field theory terms $P(A\rightarrow B)$ is made up of the product of the following two amplitudes:

1. the amplitude that a photon is created at $B$ given that there is a photon at $A$.
2. the amplitude that a photon is annihilated at $A$ given that there is a photon at $B$.

Is this the correct approach to describing a photon moving from $A$ to $B$ using creation and annihilation operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is not correct.

The propagator $D_{\mu\nu}(x-y)$ describes the amplitude for a photonic field perturbation to go from $x$ to $y$, with the implicit picture that you have a "source" $J(x)$, and a "sink" $J(y)$, which are perturbing the vaccuum.

However, a field perturbation is not a real particle (for instance, in the photon case, the Fourier transform of the propagator is not proportionnal to a delta function $\delta(k^2)$ , but rather proportionnal to $\frac{1}{k^2}$). So there is no creation or annihilation operators, because there is no real particle.

Note that, at any vertex, in momentum space, even if we work with photonic field perturbations ("virtual" photons), momenta, angular momenta, charges, etc.. are however conserved.